# Retrieving a image file from a website by passing credentials

Tags: vb6

Using Visual Basic 6.0. My code needs to pull picture images from a website and download to `c:\temp` location.

To access the website we need to pass credentials; upon successful login the images automatically downloads. Sample code:

```
'retrieve image from URL
      getURL = "http://mrldata@abc.com:8080/mrldata/compounds/" & lnumber & ".jpg?"
      Randomize
      localFile = "C:\temp\" & Hour(Now()) & Minute(Now()) & Second(Now()) & Int(Rnd * 10) & ".jpg"
      CopyURLToFile getURL, localFile
```

How can credentials be passed in order to access the website?

Comment: Visual Basic is not the same as Visual Basic for Applications.  To get the correct help, this should be tagged this as VB6 and not VBA.

Comment: The VB6 software package hosts the VBA language. VB6/VBA6 are identical languages. They have a different host (VB vs Office) and a different forms package.

Comment: No, VBA is not the same as VB6.  While there are strong syntax similarities in the base languages, their environments are quite different.

Comment: BTW:  a URL looks like: `scheme:[//[user[:password]@]host[:port]][/path][?query][#fragment]`

Comment: You probably need to post your CopyURLToFile Sub as well, if only so we know what library you're using to make the request. And how does the site need credentials? HTTP Basic Auth, some query parameters, an SSL client certificate, or something else?

Comment: The Authentication is HTTP BasicAuthentication.

Comment: The requirement is to just download an image file from the website by passing username and password. It is visual basics 6.0

Comment: @thejeshdhanda And can you post your CopyURLToFile Sub? We don't know what library it's using to make the HTTP request.